# Resolve result in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

How can I resolve `result`. Currently, my code doesn't resolve `result` and console logs "Successfully found document: [Object object]". This is MongoDB. I would appretiate any help.

```js
await dbo.collection("a").findOne({ item: "journal" }, {_id:0})
  .then(result => {
  async function rs() {
await result
  }
    rs()
    if(result) {
      console.log(`Successfully found document: ${result}.`);
    } else {
      console.log("No document matches the provided query.");
    }
    return result;
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(`Failed to find document: ${err}`));
```

This is my MongoDB document:

```js
_id:61462a7bf3c0be993bcfdc3e
item:"journal"
qty:25
size:Object
status:"A"
```

Comment: how it looks your result on mongodb?

Comment: I edited the question and provided the document in mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
const results = await dbo.collection("a").findOne({ item: "journal" })

if(!!results) {
   console.log(`Successfully found document: ${JSON.stringify(result)}.`);
}
else {
   console.log("No document matches the provided query.");
}

// rest of the logic
```

Make sure the code above that you are executing is wrapped inside an async function.

Feel free to ask any future questions.
Thanks :)